# SendMailAsync not working after deploy on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, email, asp.net-web-api

I have deployed on Azure my web api, and I'm not able to send any emails.
Everything works when I try it in local, but when I deploy it and try to send the email, I receive an error 500.

It works if I use SendGrid, but I don't want to use it !

And also, I have tried with different account : GMAIL, OVH email, it's always the same issue -> It works with localhost but not after deploy.

To send the email, I use this code :

```
var emailClient = new SmtpClient()
                    {
                        Host = "smtp.mywebsiteovh.org",
                        Port = 587,
                        //EnableSsl = true,
                        //UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@mywebsiteovh.org", "password")
                    };

var msg = new MailMessage
{
    From = new MailAddress("myemail@mywebsiteovh.org"),
    To = { new MailAddress("destination@gmail.com") },
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    Subject = "Subject",
    Body = "Body of email"
};
await emailClient.SendMailAsync(msg);
```

So I wonder if it's possible to send email from Azure without SendGrid. 
Someone can help me ? :D

Thanks a lot !!!
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GMail, you definitely need to authenticate in a browser before you can authenticate in your code because GMail requires web login from an IP before you can login via SMTP.

Since we can't open a browser from Azure Web App to validate the device, I suggest you turning on allowing less secure apps from following link.

https://myaccount.google.com/security

[image]